# JavaScript: `new RegExp('hi')` versus `RegExp('hi')`?

Tags: javascript, regex, constructor

What is the difference between `RegExp('hi')` and `new RegExp('hi')`?

Does the `new` keyword do anything here?

Comment: Constructor should be use for situations like this: `RegExp('hi' + someVariable)` where you actually construct (duh!) an expression. If you know it from the beginning go with `/hi/`.

Comment: `function MyObject(arg) { if (!(this instanceof MyObject)) return new MyObject(arg); }` is a common way to implement this yourself as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is identical

> The `RegExp` constructor is the `%RegExp%` intrinsic object and the initial value of the `RegExp` property of the global object. When `RegExp` is called as a function rather than as a constructor, it creates and initializes a new `RegExp` object. Thus the function call `RegExp(…)` is equivalent to the object creation expression `new RegExp(…)` with the same arguments.

From http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexp-constructor

Comment: I can't help but feel this should be community wiki, since there's pretty much 0 original content in this answer.

Comment: @4castle I personally don't know the criteria for an answer to be a good community wiki post. I checked http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts and not sure that being "not much original" is one of those.